# How do I run an animation when moving to the left or right in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, sprite

How do I run a sprite animation when pressing the left or right arrow keys in JavaScript? Here's my code:

```
var avatarX = 0;
var avatarY = 240;
var avatarImage;
var counter = 1;
var XWIDTH = 0;
var WIDTH = 400;
var dx = 5;
var tt;
var gameCanvas;
var context;
var moving;
var animationCounter = 1;

window.addEventListener('keydown', KeyDown);

function setUpGame() { //This is the function that is called from the html document.

    gameCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas"); //Declare a new variable & assigns it the id of the CANVAS from the html document.
    context=gameCanvas.getContext("2d");
    context.font = "18px Iceland";
    context.textBaseline = "top";

    avatarImage = new Image(); //Declaring a new variable. This is so that we can store the image at a later date.
    avatarImage.onload=function(){

    // avatarImage is now fully loaded and ready to drawImage
        context.drawImage(avatarImage, Math.random() * 100, avatarY);

    // start the timer
        tt = setInterval(function(){counTer()},1000);
        setInterval(handleTick, 25);


    }
    avatarImage.addEventListener('load', startLoop, false);
    avatarImage.src = "img/ships.png"; //Ditto from above.

}

function startLoop() {
    console.log("Detecting whether moving to the right is: " + moving);
    if(moving == 0) {
        gameLoop();
    }
}

function gameLoop() {

    setTimeout(gameLoop, 100);
    handleTick();

}

function KeyDown(evt) {
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
  case 39: /*Arrow to the right*/
      if(avatarX + dx <WIDTH && avatarX + dx >XWIDTH) {
         avatarX += dx;
         moving = 0;
      }
    break;
   case 37: /*Arrow to the left*/
      if(avatarX - dx >XWIDTH) {
         avatarX -= dx;
         moving = 1;
      } 
    break;
  }
}

function counTer() {
  if(counter == 60) {
    clearInterval(tt);
  } else {
    counter++;
  }
}

function handleTick() {
    context.clearRect(0,0,gameCanvas.width,gameCanvas.height);
    context.drawImage(avatarImage, 32*animationCounter, 0, 32,32, avatarX, avatarY, 64, 64);
    context.fillText("Seconds: " + counter, 5, 5);
    context.fillText("1 is Right, 2 is Left, 0 is idle: " + moving, 20, 20);


    animationCounter++
    if(animationCounter >1) {
        animationCounter = 0;

    }
}
```

Comment: Not what I had in mind. Want to just use JavaScript and not any plugins please.

Comment: So, what problems are you having? There is a question and a bunch of code, but the question doesn't seem to be about the code.

Comment: If you could take a look at Doozerman's answer you will get what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to implement animation. The one i use is pretty easy and looks something like this:

```
var player = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 50,
    height: 100,
    sprite: {
        column: 0,
        row: 0,
        height: 50,
        width: 100
    },
    image: PlayerImage,
    animation: {
        active: true, //Determines if the animation is running or not.
        counter: 0,
        progress: 0,
        sequence: []
    }
}

//This functions fires when the left arrow is pressed.
var onLeft = function(){
    player.animation.sequence = [{column: 0, row: 0, t: 12}, {column: 1, row: 0, t: 12}, {column: 2, row: 0, t: 12}];
    player.animation.active = true;
}

//This functions fires when the right arrow is pressed.
var onRight = function(){
    player.animation.sequence = [{column: 0, row: 1, t: 12}, {column: 1, row: 1, t: 12}, {column: 2, row: 1, t: 12}];
    player.animation.active = true;
}

//This function fires when no arrow are pressed. 
var standingStill = function(){
    player.animation.active = false;
}

var handleTick = function(){

    //Clear the canvas.
    context.canvas.width = context.canvas.width;

    //If the animation is active.
    if(player.animation.active){

        //If the counter >= tick in the sequence. If not, just keep on increasing the counter value.
        if(player.animation.counter >= player.animation.sequence[player.animation.progress]){
            player.animation.counter = 1;

            if(player.animation.progress >= player.animation.sequence.length - 1){
                player.animation.progress = 0;
            }else{
                player.animation.progress++;
            }

            var currentFrame = player.animation.sequence[player.animation.progress];

            //Change player.sprite column and row.(new frame)
            player.sprite.column = currentFrame.column;
            player.sprite.row = currentFrame.row;
        }else{
            player.animation.counter++;
        }

    }

    context.drawImage(player.image, player.sprite.column * player.sprite.width, player.sprite.row * player.sprite.height, player.sprite.width, player.sprite.height, player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height)

}
```

The sequence is an array that contains objects that look like that: `{column: 0, row: 0, t: 12}` Every object is a frame. The `column` value is the current `x` of the sprite, the `row` is the `y` of the sprite. The script automatically creates the `x` and the `y` value, so all you need to add is value like 0, 1, 3, 5, and so on.(Just which frame it is on either x or y axis.) So for example, if the column is 0 and the row is 0, this is the frame that is in the top-left corner(the first frame). The `t` value stands for tick, this determines how many ticks there has to happend before the animation goes to the next frame.

`Player.sprite` also has properties `width` and `height`, that's the width and the height of the frame, it is often the same value as the width and height of the player object.

You have to make your own `player.animation.sequence` in `onLeft` and `onRight` function so it animates how you want it to animate.

I hope you understood what i meant. This might seem complicated, but it really isn't and if you don't get it now, don't worry, you'll get it eventually. If you really have difficulties with understanding, just ask.

---

**Edit:** First of all i highly recommend using objects to store information about entities. It makes game making much easier and cleaner. Just look at the `player` object, it's much easier to get the x simply by writing `player.x` than `PlayerX`. It looks more professional too. :) And when you have to give a lot of information about your entity you don't have to pass many arguments, you pass the whole object. **Example:**

```
//Entity properties stored in separate variable.
function animate(EntityX, EntityY, EntitySpriteX, EntitySpriteY, ...){
    var x = EntityX;
    //And so on...  
}

//Entity stored in an object.
function animate(Entity){
    var x = Entity.x;
    //And so on...
}
```

Anyway, back to your question. First, we have to add variables that store information about our sprite.

```
var avatarSpriteColumn = 0; //Sprite frame on the x axis.
var avatarSpriteRow = 0; //Sprite frame on the y axis.
var avatarSpriteWidth = 50; //The width of a frame.
var avatarSpriteHeight = 100; //The height of a frame.
```

We also have to add variables that store the information about the animation.

```
var animationActive = false; //A variable that controls if the animation is 'running'.
var animationCounter = 0; //How many frames(ticks) have passed since the last frame(animation frame) has changed. (I'm not good at describing variables. :P)
var animationProgress = 0; //Current animation frame.
var animationSequence = []; //Array that stores the sequence of animation, as i explained.
```

Then, in your `handleTick` function you have to add a code that will animate the sprite. You have to add this code before you draw your entity.

```
//If the animation is active.
if(animationActive){

    //If the counter >= tick in the sequence. If not, just keep on increasing the counter value.
    if(animationCounter >= animationSequence[animationProgress]){
        animationCounter = 1;

        //Reset the progress, so that next time another animation frame shows up.
        if(animationProgress >= animationSequence.length - 1){
            animationProgress = 0;
        }else{
            animationProgress++;
        }

        //Select information about the current animation frame and store it in a variable so it is easier to access.
        var currentFrame = animationSequence[animationProgress];

        //Change player.sprite column and row.(new frame);
        avatarSpriteColumn = currentFrame.column;
        avatarSpriteRow = currentFrame.row;
    }else{
        animationCounter.counter++;
    }

}
```

Ok, now you have a code that animates the sprite, but how do we run it? Well, i see you have a variable called `moving`. It tells us in what direction the player is moving and if it is moving at all. It looks like you implemented it a little bit wrong. Right now your function that operates the keys looks like this:

```
function KeyDown(evt) {
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
  case 39: /*Arrow to the right*/
      if(avatarX + dx <WIDTH && avatarX + dx >XWIDTH) {
         avatarX += dx;
         moving = 0;
      }
    break;
   case 37: /*Arrow to the left*/
      if(avatarX - dx >XWIDTH) {
         avatarX -= dx;
         moving = 1;
      } 
    break;
  }
}
```

The variable is supposed to return 1 if the entity is going to the right, 2 if it is going to the left and 0 if the entity is standing still, right? Right now it shows 0 when the entity is moving to the right and 1 when it is moving to the left. It also doesn't show us if the entity is idle. We have to fix it. Change it to something like this:

```
function KeyDown(evt) {
    switch (evt.keyCode) {
        case 39: /*Arrow to the right*/
            if(avatarX + dx <WIDTH && avatarX + dx >XWIDTH) {
                avatarX += dx;
                moving = 1;
            }
        break;
        case 37: /*Arrow to the left*/
            if(avatarX - dx >XWIDTH) {
                avatarX -= dx;
                moving = 2;
            } 
        break;
        default:
            moving = 0;
    }
}
```

Ok, now we have to add this code to the handleTick function. This code starts the animation and changes the sequence.:

```
if(moving == 1){ //Moving in the right direction.
    animationSequence = []; //Animation of moving in the right direction. Change the sequence to your own.
    animationActive = true; //Run the animation.
}else if(moving == 2){ //Moving to the left.
    animationSequence = []; //Animation of moving to the left. Change the sequence to your own.
    animationActive = true; //Run the animation.
}else{
    animationActive = false; //Stops the animation, but the last frame stays.

    /*

    Alternatively, if you want a separate frame or animation that is animating when the entity is standing, you run this code.

    animationSequence = []; // Your sequence. If you want a single frame, with no animation just add one frame to the sequence.
    animationActive = true;

    */
}
```

Now, the last thing we have to do is to draw the entity. In your case, this will look something like this:

```
context.drawImage(avatarImage, avatarSpriteColumn * avatarSpriteWidth, avatarSpriteRow * avatarSpriteHeight, avatarWidth, avatarHeight, avatarX, avatarY, 64, 64);
```

In the end your whole code will look something like this:

```
var avatarX = 0;
var avatarY = 240;
var avatarImage;
var counter = 1;
var XWIDTH = 0;
var WIDTH = 400;
var dx = 5;
var tt;
var gameCanvas;
var context;
var moving;
var animationCounter = 1;

var avatarSpriteColumn = 0; //Sprite frame on the x axis.
var avatarSpriteRow = 0; //Sprite frame on the y axis.
var avatarSpriteWidth = 50; //The width of a frame.
var avatarSpriteHeight = 100; //The height of a frame.

var animationActive = false; //A variable that controls if the animation is 'running'.
var animationCounter = 0; //How many frames(ticks) have passed since the last frame(animation frame) has changed. (I'm not good at describing variables. :P)
var animationProgress = 0; //Current animation frame.
var animationSequence = []; //Array that stores the sequence of animation, as i explained.

window.addEventListener('keydown', KeyDown);

function setUpGame() { //This is the function that is called from the html document.

    gameCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas"); //Declare a new variable & assigns it the id of the CANVAS from the html document.
    context=gameCanvas.getContext("2d");
    context.font = "18px Iceland";
    context.textBaseline = "top";

    avatarImage = new Image(); //Declaring a new variable. This is so that we can store the image at a later date.
    avatarImage.onload=function(){

    // avatarImage is now fully loaded and ready to drawImage
        context.drawImage(avatarImage, Math.random() * 100, avatarY);

    // start the timer
        tt = setInterval(function(){counTer()},1000);
        setInterval(handleTick, 25);


    }
    avatarImage.addEventListener('load', startLoop, false);
    avatarImage.src = "img/ships.png"; //Ditto from above.

}

function startLoop() {
    console.log("Detecting whether moving to the right is: " + moving);
    if(moving == 0) {
        gameLoop();
    }
}

function gameLoop() {

    setTimeout(gameLoop, 100);
    handleTick();

}

function KeyDown(evt) {
    switch (evt.keyCode) {
        case 39: /*Arrow to the right*/
            if(avatarX + dx <WIDTH && avatarX + dx >XWIDTH) {
                avatarX += dx;
                moving = 1;
            }
        break;
        case 37: /*Arrow to the left*/
            if(avatarX - dx >XWIDTH) {
                avatarX -= dx;
                moving = 2;
            } 
        break;
        default:
            moving = 0;
    }
}

function counTer() {
  if(counter == 60) {
    clearInterval(tt);
  } else {
    counter++;
  }
}

function handleTick() {
    context.clearRect(0,0,gameCanvas.width,gameCanvas.height);

    if(moving == 1){ //Moving in the right direction.
        animationSequence = []; //Animation of moving in the right direction. Change the sequence to your own.
        animationActive = true; //Run the animation.
    }else if(moving == 2){ //Moving to the left.
        animationSequence = []; //Animation of moving to the left. Change the sequence to your own.
        animationActive = true; //Run the animation.
    }else{
        animationActive = false; //Stops the animation, but the last frame stays.

        /*

        Alternatively, if you want a separate frame or animation that is animating when the entity is standing, you run this code.

        animationSequence = []; // Your sequence. If you want a single frame, with no animation just add one frame to the sequence.
        animationActive = true;

        */
    }

    //If the animation is active.
    if(animationActive){

        //If the counter >= tick in the sequence. If not, just keep on increasing the counter value.
        if(animationCounter >= animationSequence[animationProgress]){
            animationCounter = 1;

            //Reset the progress, so that next time another animation frame shows up.
            if(animationProgress >= animationSequence.length - 1){
                animationProgress = 0;
            }else{
                animationProgress++;
            }

            //Select information about the current animation frame and store it in a variable so it is easier to access.
            var currentFrame = animationSequence[animationProgress];

            //Change player.sprite column and row.(new frame);
            avatarSpriteColumn = currentFrame.column;
            avatarSpriteRow = currentFrame.row;
        }else{
            animationCounter.counter++;
        }

    }

    context.drawImage(avatarImage, avatarSpriteColumn * avatarSpriteWidth, avatarSpriteRow * avatarSpriteHeight, avatarWidth, avatarHeight, avatarX, avatarY, 64, 64);

    context.fillText("Seconds: " + counter, 5, 5);
    context.fillText("1 is Right, 2 is Left, 0 is idle: " + moving, 20, 20);

}
```

The only thing you have to do right now is to make your own `animationSequences` and check if it works, let me know if you have any problems with that.

Of course, the code i am using is more complicated and has more "abilities" and is easier to use(the code behind is more complicated), but hopefully this will help you.

I must also apoligize for making this thing seem so complicated, when it's not. I am bad at explaining.

Comment: Very good answer but how would you do that using my code in the above question? Thanks for your help. Didn't think I'll get a answer over the holiday period. Merry Christmas & a Happy New Year to You.

Comment: @Formula1 Merry Christmas & Happy New Year to you too, check out my answer. I edited it, and added more explanation and code. Maybe this will help you.